# Django - Only allow one session per user results in Bad request

Tags: django, session, signals

for some reason I get back http 400 (Bad Request) if I login on another browser while refrshing the first. I just want to accomplish that one user can only have one active session at a time.

models.py

```
class UserSession(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    session = models.OneToOneField(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

signals.py

```
@receiver(user_logged_in)
def remove_other_sessions(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    # remove other sessions
    old_sessions = Session.objects.filter(usersession__user=user)
    if request.session.session_key:
        old_sessions = old_sessions.exclude(session_key=request.session.session_key)
    old_sessions.delete()

    # save current session
    request.session.save()

    # create a link from the user to the current session (for later removal)
    UserSession.objects.get_or_create(
        user=user,
        session=Session.objects.get(pk=request.session.session_key)
    )
```

For some reson the first browser does not delete the session, instead it keeps the session and I get back http 400 until I delete the session key manually.
I would expect that If the session key does not exist anymore the user is redirected to the login. Can smb. Help?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting the old sessions, set their `expire_date` to the current time. This way when an old session key is used the session middleware will handle the deleting of the old session as it will be "expired"

```
@receiver(user_logged_in)
def remove_other_sessions(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    # Force other sessions to expire
    old_sessions = Session.objects.filter(usersession__user=user)
    if request.session.session_key:
        old_sessions = old_sessions.exclude(session_key=request.session.session_key)
    old_sessions.update(expire_date=datetime.datetime.now())

    # save current session
    request.session.save()

    # create a link from the user to the current session (for later removal)
    UserSession.objects.get_or_create(
        user=user,
        session=Session.objects.get(pk=request.session.session_key)
    )
```

Comment: Got to verify this, thanks for now. Will mark your answere ASAP as solution

Comment: I tried your solution but if the session is set just to expired nothing happends. In other words I can have X session for one user at the same time

Comment: I have tried the solution and it is working as expected for me. Is the other session in a completely different browser or incognito tab?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/pcraston/django-preventconcurrentlogins

Comment: Why save current session, when user is already logged in with sesssion key?